# is there any need or use for a class in this case

Tags: python

## does this class have any use and how could i make it be incorporated into this code

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, race, age, height):
        self.race = race
        self.age = age
        self.height = height


race_var = input("what race are you?: ")
height_var = input("what height are you?: ")
age_var = input("what age are you?: ")
Person.race = race_var
Person.height = height_var
Person.age = age_var

print("You are of the", race_var, "race")
print("You are", height_var, "tall")
print("you are", age_var, "years old")
```

Comment: You're never creating any instances of the class.

Comment: the way you've done it the class serves no purpose. But you need to read a tutorial on OOP to understand the correct way to use classes.

Comment: Think about how that would work if you have 2 or more persons with different race, age, and height.

Answer (score 1):

You want to create an instance of the class

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, race, age, height):
        self.race = race
        self.age = age
        self.height = height

race_var = input("what race are you?: ")
height_var = input("what height are you?: ")
age_var = input("what age are you?: ")

person = Person(race_var, height_var, age_var)

print("You are of the", person.race_var, "race")
print("You are", person.height_var, "tall")
print("you are", person.age_var, "years old")
```

As for whether it is useful, well, there is some utility in associating those three values. But otherwise the class doesn't do anything a simple dict couldn't do. So, kinda useful.

Comment: Even a `tuple` would work for binding 3 pieces of information, but you'd lose the convenience of having names for them.